# psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused in Docker to a psql in Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, psql, windows-firewall

My config :

> postgreSQL 10 on Windows called "Server A" ip : 192.168.10.11 Docker
>   debian installed on "Server A"

trying to access to the database from the docker :

```
psql -U postgres -h 192.168.10.11
```

and then I get the unfamous "psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused"

Checked the C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data\posgresql.conf  with

```
listen_adresses='*'
```

and

```
port = 5432
```

Checked the C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data\pg_hba.conf with

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             samehost            trust
```

I've disabled the firewall, not without trying to make some specific rules for the port and for the application.
Also tryed :
Checked the netstat -an on "Server A" :

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I tryed also to set the log file but no info there. no info inthe event log also.
So 'i'm puzzled.
Any clue to where I should look for ?

Comment: What about the IPV6 section in pg_hba.conf?

Comment: I've commented it. Should I have not ?

Comment: Sorry I might be confusing this with an authentication issue, it's something I've come across a number of times but can't remember what the problem was that it solved :-) Seeing that you're connecting to a remote host, it's probably not that.

Comment: I can connect in local thought.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue. seems that the Ip adresse wasn't the good one. 
not 192.168.10.11 but 192.168.10.17.

It start tho with a error message like "psql : could not translate host name "example.hotdb.com" to address: Name or service not known"

so I replaced with the IP adresses I thought it should be instead of checking the IP adresse it really was. 
so a ipconfig gave me the right IP I should psql to and then I connected.